# "Just do it" in Spanish

Tags: traducción, español-neutral

I am trying to translate the famous Nike tagline in the most natural Spanish possible. From what I have learned at SE and elsewhere, I have come up with:

> **Sólo hazlo**

But I am curious to see if there's another more natural alternative to words like **sólo** or **solamente** in such contexts. How would a native speaker render this thought?

Comment: From what I have seen on the internet, even Nike didn't do this!

Comment: According to the translation Wikipedia offers, *sólo hazlo* seems to be just fine.

Comment: On another topic, now [the RAE recommends writing *solo* without accent mark](http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-adverbio-solo-y-los-pronombres-demostrativos-sin-tilde), although writing it is still correct. This should make it easier for Spanish learners because it now follows the standard accentuation rules.

Comment: extremely regional possibility: _vos dale_

Answer (score 9):

I would say `Simplemente hazlo`, although depending on the context it would be better to say `hazlo de una vez` (similar to `do it already`).

Comment: Me too. I would add a comma between: "Simplemente, hazlo". To stress Nike's point. In more informal contexts, even a colon: "Simplemente: hazlo".

Comment: La traducción del último sería "do it now", no "already".

Answer (score 1):

"Just do it" could also be translated as

> Tan sólo hazlo.

but I don't know how well it would convey the meaning of such a famous tagline as Nike's.

Answer (score 1):

> Solo hágalo

One of various [examples from converso.net](https://context.reverso.net/traduccion/espanol-ingles/S%C3%B3lo+h%C3%A1galo#just+do+it):

> Si usted quiere visitar las Siete Maravillas del Mundo en un día o ir a la Luna, sólo hágalo. ¡Nada es imposible!
>
> (If you want to visit the Seven Wonders of the World for one day or go to the Moon, just do it. Nothing is impossible!)

(There are also enough examples for the other proposed translations.)

P.S.: I didn't write "*sólo*" with *tilde*. This hadn't been intentional (I learnt it differently), but it's actually the correct way according to the Spanish Royal Academy: *[La recomendación general es, pues, la de no tildar nunca estas palabras.](http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-adverbio-solo-y-los-pronombres-demostrativos-sin-tilde)*

Answer (score 1):

**Hazlo y ya.**

Sounds more Madison Avenue to me than the other proposals.

Comment: What does "Madison Avenue" sound like?

Comment: @Charlie - Oh, sorry!  "Madison Avenue" is to advertising as Hollywood is to mainstream movies.

Answer (score -1):

When you are going to execute an action you simply have to say "solo hazlo".

Comment: Por tu respuesta parece que estás de acuerdo con la propuesta que TheLearner hizo en la pregunta. Personalmente me parece bien pero si puedes explicar los motivos de tu decisión y en qué difiere tu respuesta de otras similares, mucho mejor. Cuanto más escribas y razones más votaremos tus respuestas. Y si ves que otras respuestas ya expresan lo que tú quieres decir, es mejor que votes esas respuestas en vez de escribir una nueva. Consulta la sección [answer] para más información. ¡Bienvenido al sitio!